# java null object reference error / I want my TextView changes color and text when I click the button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7ulz.png)

Logcat says 15th line has error. But I don't know the reason. :( I'm noob so plz explain me softly plz..

Down below is the whole content of logcat.

...
2020-10-17 16:50:03.488 9840-9840/? E/city_implement: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-10-17 16:50:04.351 9840-9840/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.acticity_implements, PID: 9840
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.acticity_implements/com.example.acticity_implements.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.acticity_implements.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
...

xml code of buttonRed is this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2TpJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be broken down quite clear, from top to bottom:

1. Line 15 throws a `NullPointerException` and has two references: `buttonRed` and `this`. `this` cannot be ever null, so it must be `buttonRed`.
2. On line 14 `findViewById` is used to get the reference to the button, this apparently returns null.

This is, because you do not set your layout yet and there is no button. If you remove all code from `onCreate`, you will see you get a white screen without buttons.

Call `setcontentview(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT)` in `onCreate`, right after `super.onCreate()`

Comment: My English is bad so I don't know How to express my thankful mind fully. I really really appreciate with your kind and helpful answer. Thank you so much!! :D